# For Loop not giving correct results in R

Tags: r

I am trying to rename my Dataframe columns from 5th column to the total number of columns in my dataframe. Below, is the R loop which i have coded to rename.

```
for(i in 5:NCOL(raw_data_ui)){
  colnames(raw_data_ui[i]) <- paste(substr(colnames(raw_data_ui[i]),7,9), substr(colnames(raw_data_ui[i]),11,14), sep = "-")
}
```

But, My code didn't change the column name. For example my 5th column name is "Count.Feb.2015". After running the above code the name didn't change.

Could anyone tell me as what went wrong in my code.

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: try `colnames(raw_data_ui)[i]` instead of `colnames(raw_data_ui[i])`.  If that does not work, post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the i'th colname, that is why the brackets need to stand after after the closing parenthesis as in

```
colnames(raw_data_ui)[i]
```

To give a clearer view, some sore simpler example:

```
d <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Your version of

```
colnames(d[2])<-"Y"
```

will create a new instance/entity, which is the second row of d. A copy will be created once you change anything, like the name, and the link to `d` is lost.

```
colnames(d)[2]<-"Y"
```

will change the second name and the reference to d is intact.